# /var/log/secure with group: root mask: 177 owner: root system: Linux

Tags: rhel

Anyone can explain to me what does below hardening scan mean?

```
Actual Value: The file /var/log/secure with fmode owner: root group: root mode: 0622 uid: 0 gid: 0 uneven permissions : FALSE  does not match the policy value owner: root group: root mask: 0177 uneven permissions : TRUE 

/var/log/secure

Policy Value: file: /var/log/secure
group: root
mask: 177
owner: root
system: Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a mismatch between the actual permissions of the `/var/log/secure` file (`0622`, `-rw-r--r--`), and the file permissions of a file created under the `0177` mask value (`0600`, `-rw-------`).

This is a possible "somebody has messed with the system" alarm. But, maybe not. Thus, the warning.

Further investigation is needed. Who? When? Why? Is this the only error?